Auto-expand and auto-scroll in MudBlazor with MudTree
I am trying to create a Comments component which renders comments, but the comments can have nested comments, and I want to be able to fetch the child comments only if the users clicks on the parent comment, hence the loop.
There is an issue with this, because it creates a new TreeView for each comment, but I must have the comment Id in order to fetch the child comments and I can't do anything about how the api is created, because I am aware that this is not the optimal way of fetching nested comments.
This setup works, but because it creates many TreeViews, when a child component is expanded, it squeezes the rest of the trees and it does not look optimal.
Second, I want to be able to auto expand, and scroll to item at a TreeViewItem with a given id. I tested with a fixed id, but it does not auto expand to that item.
Below is my code, and if you have any suggestions, please let me know.
@foreach(var item in comments)
{
    <MudTreeView Hover ExpandOnClick
                    SelectionMode="SelectionMode.SingleSelection"
                    AutoExpand @bind-SelectedValue="SelectedValue"
                    ServerData="@((e) => LoadServerData(e, item.Id))"
                    Items="@InitialTreeItems">
        <MudTreeViewItem Value="@item.content">
                    @foreach(var exp in childComments.expand)
                    {
                        <MudTreeViewItem id="@exp.parentId" Class="my-1" Value="@exp.commentId" Text="@exp.content" ExpandedChanged="() => GetCommentsByParentId(exp.parentId)">
                            <ExternalCard />
                        </MudTreeViewItem>
                    }
        </MudTreeViewItem>
    </MudTreeView>
}

@code {
    private List<TreeItemData<string>> InitialTreeItems { get; set; } = new();
    private List<TreeItemData<string>> ServerTreeItems { get; set; } = new();
    public string SelectedValue = null;
    public List<Comment> comments;
    public List<Comment> childComments;
}

// comments and child comments gets populated on demand.

protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    // Initialize top-level items
}

public async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<TreeItemData<string>>> LoadServerData(string parentValue)
{
    // populates comments;
}

private async Task GetCommentsByParentId(string commentId)
{
    // populates childComments;
}

I have been experimenting with this and this snippets from MudBlazor official documentation site.

It is a good idea to manage an expanding state, btw I suggest not define too many lists of your comment to avoid the squeezing issue. To implement auto expand and scrolling, js would be a feasible way to customize and ensure flexibility. In my test , need to pay attention to scrolling circulation.

After more test I found js way not feasible as the DOM element is not rendered when selecting id on the page, so the scrolling will not work in js. And in your code there is no sample code of auto-expand from MudBlazor, may I ask what is the problem?

Here's a treeview that loads the comments as needed when you either click the arrow or select a comment. It should give you a very good starting point and does not require you to load multiple treeviews. Here's a link to a TryMudBlazor sample. You will notice my "Comments" class is a view model class where I add the extra properties I needed for this to work. Please let me know if you have any questions, and obviously where I LoadServerData instead of Comments.Where I would hit the api.
First I create fake data for both parent and children and store it in one class - Comments. OnInit I get all the parent components from that storage and put into the TreeViewItems list. The initial TreeView loads those items. Anytime you try to expand an item it will hit LoadServerData and where I var childComments I'm fetching children from the Comments class, in your case you would fetch from api.
Nested TreeView
The highlights of the code are:
Razor
<MudTreeView T="Comment" Items="TreeViewItems" ServerData="@LoadServerData" ExpandOnClick="true" @bind-SelectedValue="_selectedComment">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <MudTreeViewItem Text="@context.Text" Value="context.Value" 
            ExpandButtonIcon="@(context.Value!.HasChild ? Icons.Material.Filled.KeyboardArrowRight : string.Empty)" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</MudTreeView>

@codeblock
@code {
    private List<Comment> Comments = new();
    private IReadOnlyCollection<TreeItemData<Comment>> TreeViewItems = Array.Empty<TreeItemData<Comment>>();
    private Comment? _selectedComment;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        // get a set of comments to work on
        Comments = CommentGenerator.GenerateComments();
        // only load top level comments like the api lets us
        TreeViewItems = Comments.Where(c => c.ParentId == null).Select(c => new TreeItemData<Comment>()
            {
                Expandable = c.HasChild,
                Expanded = false,
                Text = c.Content,
                Value = c,
            }).ToList();
    }

    private async Task<IReadOnlyCollection<TreeItemData<Comment>>> LoadServerData(Comment parentValue)
    {
        await Task.CompletedTask;
        _selectedComment = parentValue;
        StateHasChanged();
        // grab the children of the parent clicked if we don't have them loaded yet
        if (parentValue.HasChild && !parentValue.ChildrenLoaded)
        {
            var childComments = Comments
                                .Where(c => c.ParentId == parentValue.Id)
                                .ToList();

            var treeItems = childComments.Select(c => new TreeItemData<Comment>()
                {
                    Expandable = c.HasChild,
                    Text = c.Content,
                    Value = c,
                }).ToList();

            // Mark the parent as having loaded its children
            parentValue.ChildrenLoaded = true;

            return treeItems;
        }

        return [];
    }
}


Auto expand would be easy as you'd just need to set the _selectedComment to whatever comment you are looking for and it would automatically expand that segment.

How can I get the child comments with a parent comment Id? I think you discarded that requirement from your code.

every one has a parentID field, this part finds the child with the id of the parent in the LoadServerData method             var childComments = Comments                                 .Where(c => c.ParentId == parentValue.Id)                                 .ToList(); Which means the children are being loaded dynamically. When you expand it loads the child. You would just replace that line with something getting from the api. If your initial api call doesn't pull whether or not it has a child then you would skip HasChild field and modify the spots where I'm using it.

The problem is that I have to fetch the children comments on demand, and not all of the items at the same time on initialized. I added a function call on ExpandedChanged which fetches the children comments, but it does not re-render the tree with the added children to the list.

You don't need to have another function call. In the server data where I var childComments that's where you load children. I'm in discord mudblazor if you want to chat. https://discord.gg/uvbtTx6U
